# String.Contains() vazio retornando verdadeiro

Tags: c#, .net, string

Por que ao utilizar o `Contains("")` em uma `string` não vazia retorna verdadeiro?

Exemplo

```
if ("MinhaString".Contains(""))
{
    Console.WriteLine("String contém vazio");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podemos dizer que é uma convenção. A ideia é que toda *string* tem uma *string* vazia.

Uma *string* é composta no mínimo de uma *string* vazia, e provavelmente outros caracteres **em adição** ao vazio.

Isto deveria ser verdadeiro ou falso?

```
"" == ""
```

Imagino que todos aceitam como verdadeiro.

O `Contains()` pergunta se o "nada" está dentro de uma *string* e está. Consideramos que todo caractere está empermeado por um "nada". Mesmo que não tenha caracteres o nada está lá presente.

Então:

```
"abc" == "abc" + ""
```

Certo?

Ambos retornam que tem nada, porque ambos tem. O primeiro você não vê que tem, o segundo você vê. Só porque você não vê não quer dizer que não está lá.

Poderia perguntar porque não consideraram que nada não existe e nunca está em lugar algum. E eu te perguntaria que ganho espera ter com isto?

Se não tem o que comparar que resultado daria?

Até o `null` é igual a `null`. Então seria inconsistente.

Uma coisa é você perguntar se uma *string* tem um vazio, outra bem diferente é perguntar se ela é toda vazia, então

```
"abc" != ""
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/ContainsBehavior.cs).

Esta pergunta quer saber se todos os caracteres são iguais, até o vazio. E o vazio é igual, mas os outros 3 visíveis só tem em uma *string*, há pelo menos uma diferença entre as duas *strings*, isto faz tudo ser diferente.

O `==` é como se fosse um `&&` em todos os caracteres, já o `Contains()` é como se fosse um `||`. Se ele achar uma ocorrência da agulha no palheiro já é tudo verdadeiro, e o vazio está presente em toda *string*, por definição, então sempre retornaria verdadeiro.

Comment: Não entendi a sua pergunta de que se ""=="" deve ser verdadeiro ou não. Poderia explicar como isso se encaixa melhor no contexto da minha pergunta? Pois se eu testar "MinhaString"=="" var retornar falso.

Comment: @PabloTondolodeVargas melhorou?

Comment: @Maniero está parecendo mais uma discussão de ordem filosófica ("Só porque você não vê não quer dizer que não está lá."), mas resumidamente eu entendo que: toda string contém "nada" por convenção.

Comment: @PabloTondolodeVargas é meio metafísico :D